# Specular lighting in LWJGL 3 not working [Phong Shading]

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, fragment-shader, lighting, phong

I implemented lighting in my engine. But there is some problem the object does not lights up properly
[image: The object that gets rendered] The specular lighting does not work at all

Here is the vertex shader :

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 tex_coords;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normals;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 worldMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

out vec2 coords;
out vec3 vertexNormals;
out vec3 vertexPos;

void main() {
    vec4 mVerPos = worldMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    coords = tex_coords;
    vertexNormals = normalize(worldMatrix * vec4(normals, 0.0)).xyz;
    vertexPos = mVerPos.xyz;
}
```

Here is the fragment shader :

```
#version 330

struct Material {
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    int hasTexture;
    float reflectance;
};

struct PointLight {
    vec3 color;
    vec3 position;
    float intensity;
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float exponent;
};

struct DirLight {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
    float intensity;
};

out vec4 fragColor;

in vec2 coords;
in vec3 vertexNormals;
in vec3 vertexPos;

uniform sampler2D sampler;
uniform vec3 ambientColor;
uniform Material material;
uniform PointLight pointLight;
uniform float specularPower;
uniform DirLight dirLight;

vec4 ambientC;
vec4 diffuseC;
vec4 specularC;

void setUpColor(Material material, vec2 coords) {
    if (material.hasTexture == 1) {
        ambientC = texture(sampler, coords);
        diffuseC = ambientC;
        specularC = ambientC;
    }
    else {
        ambientC = material.ambient;
        diffuseC = material.diffuse;
        specularC = material.specular;
    }
}

vec4 calcLightColor(vec3 lightColor, float lightIntensity, vec3 position, vec3 to_light_dir, vec3 normal) {
    vec4 diffuseColour = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    vec4 specColour = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Diffuse Light
    float diffuseFactor = max(dot(normal, to_light_dir ), 0.0);
    diffuseColour = diffuseC * vec4(lightColor, 1.0) * lightIntensity * diffuseFactor;

    // Specular Light
    vec3 camera_direction = normalize(-position);
    vec3 from_light_dir = -to_light_dir;
    vec3 reflected_light = normalize(reflect(from_light_dir, normal));
    float specularFactor = max(dot(camera_direction, reflected_light), 0.0);
    specularFactor = pow(specularFactor, specularPower);
    specColour = specularC * lightIntensity * specularFactor * material.reflectance * vec4(lightColor, 1.0);
    
    return (diffuseColour + specColour);
};


vec4 calcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 position, vec3 normal)
{
    vec3 light_direction = light.position - position;
    vec3 to_light_source  = normalize(light_direction);
    vec4 lightColor = calcLightColor(light.color, light.intensity, position, to_light_source, normal);

    // Attenuation
    float distance = length(light_direction);
    float attenuationInv = light.constant + light.linear * distance +
        light.exponent * distance * distance;
    return lightColor / attenuationInv;
}

vec4 calcDirLight(DirLight light, vec3 position, vec3 normal) {
    return calcLightColor(light.color, light.intensity, position, normalize(light.position), normal);
}

void main() {

    setUpColor(material, coords);
    vec4 diffuseSpecularComp = calcDirLight(dirLight, vertexPos, vertexNormals);
    diffuseSpecularComp += calcPointLight(pointLight, vertexPos, vertexNormals);
    fragColor = ambientC * vec4(ambientColor, 1) + diffuseSpecularComp;
    
}
```

Here is the source code : https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/hwlnz913jm6c9xli2dsb6/h?dl=0&rlkey=b2zj0w6kttwu3b1di9rejwnq3

When I changed the value of zero at `float diffuseFactor = max(dot(normal, to_light_dir ), 0.0);` and at `float specularFactor = max(dot(camera_direction, reflected_light), 0.0);` the to something above like 0.1
this what I get [image: Later result] but the specular does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code, but I'm not entirely sure which causes the problem.

### Problems

- In the vertex shader, you don't calculate `vertexNormals` correctly. It shouldn't be a problem in your specific case, because seemingly you don't scale your mesh nonuniformly, but it's worth mentioning because it's a common mistake. You multiply the object space normal with the world matrix, but you should instead multiply it with the inverse transposed of the world matrix.
- In the fragment shader you use directly the `vertexNormals`, but it's not correct. Although you normalized the normal in the vertex shader, but the fragment shader doesn't get that specific vector. It gets the linear interpolation (basically a weighted average) of the 3 `vertexNormals` and the result is not necessarily normalized. So you should normalize it in the fragment shader as well.
- In the `setUpColor` function, why do you assign the same value to `ambientC`, `diffuseC`, and `specularC`? Usually, there are different textures for these, but at least for diffuse and specular.

### Other random observations

- In the vertex shader, you multiply the `position` twice with `worldMatrix`, but why? It seems like wasted performance (maybe the compiler optimizes it).
- In the `DirLight` struct you have a `position` member, but directional lights don't have a position, they just have a direction. I see that you compute the direction from the position, but it seems unusual.
- In the same vein the camera is always at the origin and the directional light's direction always points to the origin. If it's intentional, it's okay, it just seems unusual.
- In the `Material` struct (and in other places) you use `vec4`s instead of `vec3`s, but I guess, the last components are always ones. It's a waste of memory, you could just set the alpha value to `1.0f` at the end of `main`.

Joey de Vries has [amazing tutorials, including the Phong shading](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting) (using C++). In the *One last thing* section he also explains why it's important to use the inverse transposed matrix to transform the normal.